# Trying to merge 2 dataframes in pandas based on multiindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes and currently the values for the 2nd dataframe are being appended on the bottom of the first one when I want it included as an additional column.

1st dataframe

```
┌──────────┬────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────┬────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ filename │    date    │   txVolume(USD)    │ adjustedTxVolume(USD) │ txCount │ marketcap(USD) │ price(USD) │ exchangeVolume(USD) │        fees        │ activeAddresses │ medianTxValue(USD) │ medianFee │ paymentCount │ generatedCoins │ averageDifficulty │ blockSize │ blockCount │ value │
├──────────┼────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┼────────────┼───────┤
│ ada      │ 2017-10-01 │ 436003334.53699994 │         131165286.735 │  3096.0 │            0.0 │   0.021678 │          50068700.0 │         291.170785 │          5973.0 │       18065.296266 │   0.17107 │       1661.0 │                │                   │           │            │       │
│ ada      │ 2017-10-02 │      1025157737.96 │          151391424.74 │  2943.0 │            0.0 │   0.024607 │          57641300.0 │ 316.07460299999997 │          5858.0 │ 24206.767144999998 │   0.17107 │       1792.0 │                │                   │           │            │       │
│ ada      │ 2017-10-03 │       604612406.44 │         125245327.846 │  1808.0 │    624650688.0 │   0.025757 │          16997800.0 │ 182.28098300000002 │          3701.0 │ 21063.743716900004 │   0.17107 │       1018.0 │                │                   │           │            │       │
└──────────┴────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────┴────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

2nd dataframe:

```
┌──────────┬────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ filename │    date    │ monthly percentage price change │
├──────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ ada      │ 2017-10-31 │                                 │
│ ada      │ 2017-11-30 │              2.3253932111955717 │
│ ada      │ 2017-12-31 │               5.768998209206785 │
│ ada      │ 2018-01-31 │            -0.17893930881865483 │
└──────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

I want to include the 'monthly % price column' on the end of a consolidated dataframe based on the keys: 'filename' and 'date'.  Below is the code I've written to get to this point.  I'm still a complete newbie so I apologise in advance for my badly written code:

```
# get data file names
path =r'C:\Users\david\Documents\Crypto\Crypto_historical_data'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# Create a list called 'data':
data = []
# Include filename as a column in the dataframe
for csv in filenames:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    #frame['filename'] creates a new column named filename
    # os.path.basename() turns a path like /a/d/c.txt into the filename c.txt
    frame['filename'] = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv))[0]
    data.append(frame)

# Load all data in to the dataframe
df = pd.concat(data, sort=False)

# Filter out any rows where price is blank
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['price(USD)'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['filename', 'date'], inplace=False)

# You now have all prices sorted by date & by currency


# Exclude ctxc and ven as they are < 6 months old
df1 = df1.query('filename != ["ctxc", "ven"]')



# Get end of month prices
# Sets date as DateTime format:
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
# Sets date column as the index
# Groups data by each coin
# Converts daily to monthly prices, taking last price of the month
df2 = df1.set_index('date').groupby('filename').resample('M')['price(USD)'].last()


# Calculate monthly returns for each coin
df2 = df2.pct_change()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'price(USD)':'monthly percentage price change'})


# Merge monthly returns in to df1

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True,how='outer')
```

When trying to merge I get the error:
"ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names"

I'm hoping someone can tell me the most efficient way to add the monthly percentage change column on the end of the dataframe, using 'filename' and 'date' as the keys, ensuring that I don't lose any data from the 1st dataframe.  Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me - I've been pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: EDIT : I should have mentioned that the same combination of filename and dates exist in both dataframes.  As re-reading my post, I realise I didn't make this explicit.  So for example, I want to append the % price change of 2.3253932111955717 on the same row in the 1st data frame where filename = 'ada' and date = '2017-11-30'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True,how='outer')`

to

`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['filename','date'] ,how='outer')`

Comment: Why is it not possible to merge on joined indices?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just need to reset the index on `df2`.

When you do the groupby, I believe that will return a dataframe with a MultiIndex. Then when you go to merge, you have `df1` with a regular integer index and `df2` with a MultiIndex of date and filename.

I think if you make these your last two lines it will work

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date', 'filename'], how='outer')
```